# Can't extract specific substr to new variable using str_match_all in r

Tags: r, substr

I am trying to use str_match_all to get specific phrases from an existing variable.

Specifically, I am making new variables to reflect the different stages of moderation, which are lumped together as a long string in the variable.

For example, my variable Moderation.history shows:

From "Submitted to QM" --> "Published" on 06/06/2019 - 09:16 by user@example.com From "Under revision request" --> "Submitted to QM" on 23/05/2019 - 11:42 by Andyprendergast From "Submitted to QM" --> "Under revision request" on 20/05/2019 - 15:10 by user@example.com From "Submitted to QM" --> "Submitted to QM" on 15/05/2019 - 17:14 by user@example.com From "Draft" --> "Submitted to QM" on 13/05/2019 - 10:13 by Andyprendergast

I only need the 'status' succeeding the term 'From'. E.g., "Submitted to QM", then "Under Revision Request", and so on.

However, the code I am running works, but does not recognise the characters!

I tried to read in my data and create a test dataframe (df1).

The variables I gave df1 reflect the information I need to extract from original variable Moderation.history.

**I currently, cannot get past the first variable "from". The code is:**

from <- str_match_all(col1,"(?<= From).+(?>=\s)")[[1]][,1]

**The test data I am using (in col1) is:**

From "Submitted to QM" --> "Published" on 06/06/2019 - 09:16 by user@example.com From "Under revision request" --> "Submitted to QM" on 23/05/2019 - 11:42 by Andyprendergast From "Submitted to QM" --> "Under revision request" on 20/05/2019 - 15:10 by user@example.com From "Submitted to QM" --> "Submitted to QM" on 15/05/2019 - 17:14 by user@example.com From "Draft" --> "Submitted to QM" on 13/05/2019 - 10:13 by Andyprendergast

For reference, here is my full code below. However, I still can't get past "from", so the rest doesn't really matter at this point.

#---**mtaking df** -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
`#newERM2019Over <- read.csv("ERM Events2019over.csv", fileEncoding="latin1")
#ERM2019Over$NodeID <- neERM2019Over$Node.ID
df1 <-data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=0))
names(df1) <- c("NodeID","from","to","date", "user_responsible")

for(i in 1:nrow(newERM2019Over)){
  
  col1 <- unlist(newERM2019Over[i,"Moderation.history"])
  
  # ---- making variables
  as.character(col1)
  from <- str_match_all(col1,"(?<= From).+(?>=\\s)")[[1]][,1]
  str_view(col1,"-->")
  link <- str_match_all(col1, "(?<=Link:).+(?=Date)")[[1]][,1]
  date <- str_match_all(col1,"(?<=Date:).+(?<=\\d{4})")[[1]][,1]
  
  # ---- 
  
  tmp <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=length(source)))
  names(tmp) <- c("NodeID","from","to","date", "user_responsible")
  
  tmp$NodeID <- as.character(newERM2019Over[i, "NodeID"])
  tmp$source <- source
  tmp$link <- link
  tmp$date <- date
  
  df <- rbind(df,tmp)
}
library(tidyverse)
df$NodeID <- as.numeric(df$NodeID)
newERM2019Over_Mod_History <- left_join(newERM2019Over, df, by ="NodeID")
```

Comment: You could improve this question to get faster, better help if you focus it some and provide a reproducible example with data. There is quite a lot of text and code here but most of it is unhelpful. Really boiling your question down to minimal text and code needed to reproduce the problem will help people help you. Good luck!

Comment: Please do not use real names or real e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion to swap out `"(?<= From).+(?>=\s)"`
for `From\\s"([^"]*)"`

---

users commented on the above ; here is extended version :

```
example_text <- 'From "Submitted to QM" --> "Published" on 06/06/2019 - 09:16 by vasileios.axelos@eurofound.europa.eu From "Under revision request" --> "Submitted to QM" on 23/05/2019 - 11:42 by Andyprendergast From "Submitted to QM" --> "Under revision request" on 20/05/2019 - 15:10 by vasileios.axelos@eurofound.europa.eu From "Submitted to QM" --> "Submitted to QM" on 15/05/2019 - 17:14 by vasileios.axelos@eurofound.europa.eu From "Draft" --> "Submitted to QM" on 13/05/2019 - 10:13 by Andyprendergast'

library(tidyverse)
(original_posters_regex_result <- str_match_all(example_text,
                                                "(?<= From).+(?>=\\s)")[[1]][,1])
# character(0)

(my_suggestion <- str_match_all(example_text,
                                'From\\s"([^"]*)"'))
# [[1]]
# [,1]                              [,2]                    
# [1,] "From \"Submitted to QM\""        "Submitted to QM"       
# [2,] "From \"Under revision request\"" "Under revision request"
# [3,] "From \"Submitted to QM\""        "Submitted to QM"       
# [4,] "From \"Submitted to QM\""        "Submitted to QM"       
# [5,] "From \"Draft\""                  "Draft"
```

Comment: Your suggested replacement is not valid regex